# Warn when leaving scope with unsaved property values

Tags: api, .net-3.5

We have our own custom ORM wrapper with classes like `Contact`, `Company`, etc., which have properties such as `Name`, `Address`, and so on. You "create" an instance of a class, which implicitly downloads the current record from the database:

```
// fetch a contact with ID myRecordID from connection myConnection
Contact myContact = Contact.Create(myRecordID, myConnection);
myContact.Birthday = Date.Now;
```

Here's the thing: for performance reasons (plus other considerations such as transactions), saving *doesn't* happen implicitly when setting a property. Instead, you have to call `save()`:

```
myContact.save(); // great! the new birthday is in the database
```

This works great — except when you *forget* to call `save()`. The compiler won't see an issue, but *the above code doesn't do anything useful without saving*.

I'm wondering whether the API can let the compiler know that, when properties have been set, the compiler should warn if `save()` *isn't* called before the `Contact` instance leaves scope.

Comment: Do you have unit/integration tests?

Comment: A unit test would only confirm what I already know: the birthday hasn't been set. It wouldn't tell me why.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to implement something to let your code know that the entity has been changed. For example by implementing INotifyPropertyChanged in your entities and listening for a change. Raise property changed on every property that needs to be persisted to the database.

When the contact has been changed you can even automatically save the contact at the end of a transaction. Of course you need to add the infrastructure code.

Comment: That doesn't really help me; I'd need a way for the API to detect that scope has been left.